# If enter n is input and the output is in n digits and starting with (n-1)0 with 1 to (n-1)9's?

Tags: java

I have tried this program many times I didn't get the proper output till now please help me to solve this type of program.

input:n=3

output: 001 to 999

input:n=4

output:0001 to 9999

input:n=2

output:01 to 99

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    int sum=1,result=0;
    while(number!=0)
    {
        result=result+(9*sum);
        sum=sum*10;
        number--;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    for(int i=1;i<=result;i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%02d ",i);//here i manually mentioned the %02d  but i want to take user input
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Hint: you can store the mask as a String `String mask = "%02d"; System.out.printf(mask, 5);`

Comment: You can use Math.pow to compute the max. number: Math.pow(10, n)-1.

Comment: Where is the problem? the code is working fine.

Comment: @RalfRenz I do not think the is the problem.  The OP needs to know how to print `01` or `001` or `0001` based upon the input

Comment: @Scary Wombat oh.. I see now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
    int number = 3;
    String mask = "%0" + (number) + "d%n";
    int max = (int)Math.pow(10, number)-1;

    for (int x = 1; x <= max; x++)
        System.out.printf(mask, x);
```

**thanks** to [@RalfRenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4197431/ralf-renz)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try below code ?

```
class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    String masked = "%0" + (num) + "d%n";
    int max = (int)Math.pow(10, num)-1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= max; k++)
        System.out.printf(masked, k);
}}
```

Comment: How does this differ from my answer?

Comment: apart from int number = 3; almost same instead of that we can read from console.

Comment: OP, did not have a problem with part of the code and coded it the same as your copy.  The rest is the same as my code.  Is there any original code from you?